# Rewrite rule pagination on different url levels

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, hooks

I have a custom post type called `shop` with product posts in it. This post type is connected to a taxonomy `shop-category`, to specify a product section inside the shop.

Each product has a `item_width` and `item_height` custom fields. And as you can see below I made some urls to filter the products by width and height:

```
https://www.example.com/shop-category/product/
https://www.example.com/shop-category/product/80/
https://www.example.com/shop-category/product/80/200/
https://www.example.com/shop-category/product/80/200/page/2/
```

The last two levels of the last url (/page/2/) are set when you use the pagination to navigate to the next page with products. At the moment you can only visit this page when the `item_width` and `item_height` query parameters are set. Now I am questioning if it possible to make this also work when the `item_width` and `item_height` are not set.

So for example with the following url:

```
https://www.example.com/shop-category/product/page/2/
```

**Added variables and added rewrite rules:**

```
// Adds query vars for shop post type
function gtp_add_shop_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'shop-category';
    $vars[] = 'item_width';
    $vars[] = 'item_height';
    return $vars;       
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'gtp_add_shop_query_vars' );

// Adds rewrite rules for shop post type
function gtp_add_shop_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&item_width=$matches[2]&item_height=$matches[3]&page=$matches[4]&paged=$matches[5]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&item_width=$matches[2]&item_height=$matches[3]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&item_width=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-category/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'gtp_add_shop_rewrite_rules', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added extra rewrite rules for pages with no `item_width` and `item_height` in combination with pagination as follows:

```
/** 
 * Adds rewrite rules for shop category
 */  
function gtp_add_shop_rewrite_rules() {

    // shop-category/category/item_width/item_height/page/2/
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-category\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/page\/([0-9]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&item_width=$matches[2]&item_height=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]', 'top' );

    // shop-category/category/page/2/
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-category\/([^/]*)\/page\/([0-9]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );

    // /shop-category/category/item_width/item_height/
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-category\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&item_width=$matches[2]&item_height=$matches[3]', 'top' );

    // /shop-category/category/item_width/
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-category\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&item_width=$matches[2]', 'top' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'gtp_add_shop_rewrite_rules', 10, 0 );
```